# Clojure functions that yield "internal cartesian products" in a collection

Tags: clojure

Given the list:

```
'( [:a [:a1 :a2]]  [:b [:b1 :b2 :b3]] )
```

How can I generate the list:

```
'( [:a :a1] [:a :a1] [:b :b1] [:b :b2] [:b :b3] )
```

(that's some kind of element-expanding cartesian product combined with 1-level flattening)

The best I could come up with is:

```
(apply concat (map #(for [v (second %)] (vector (first %) v)) TheList))
```

which seems overly complex; What's a more idiomatic way to achieve it?

Also, what family of functions should one consider when trying to perform this kind of element-expanding cartesian-product-thing inside a list? (I am totally at loss on how to describe it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in the following way. It uses destructuring along with mapcat to simplify the expression:

```
(mapcat (fn [[a b]] (map #(vector a %) b)) theList)
```

In general mapcat (or flatmap/collect/selectmany in other languages) is good for dealing with nested collections you want to flatten while transforming them.

Comment: I'd use `(partial vector a)` instead of `#(vector a %)`, though it is bit longer.

Answer (score 5):

Another one:

```
(for [[x inner-xs] theList
      inner-x      inner-xs]
  [x inner-x])
```

`for` is extremely useful for nested collections and flat result.